# Laravel relationship Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent-relationship, mysql-error-1052

I have courses and subscription types.
I want to get all the courses that has a given subscription type.
My attempt:

```
$courses=Course::wherehas('subscriptionType',function ($q)
        {
            return $q->where('id','1');
        })->get();
```

But this fails:

> Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

Any tips on doing this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I tested you code and it was working fine without any changes. May be something is wrong with your relationship definitions.

However you can make it run by making following changes.

replace **return $q->where('id','1');** with **return $q->where('subscriptiontypes.id','1');** I assumed that table name for subscriptiontype model is subscriptiontypes.

full code is shown below:

```
$courses=Course::wherehas('subscriptiontype',function ($q)
        {
            return $q->where('subscriptiontypes.id','1');
        })->get();
```