# How to get automatic id column name for polymorphic manyToMany relationship subquerying?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

The below function allows me to retrieve related entries of a given model type that have, for instance, overlapping tags associated with them.

```
<?php

public function getRelated($entity, $fields = [], $relations = []) {
    $related = new EloquentCollection();

    // get models of same entity type that have relations in common

    if (count($relations)) {
        foreach ($relations as $relation) {
            // check if the current model in use has any of the currently iterated relationship at all
            if ($entity->{$relation}()->exists()) {
                // if yes, get all the ids of the related models, for instance tags
                $relationIds = $entity->{$relation}()->get()->pluck('id')->toArray();

                // now, get all same type models except the current one
                $relationEntities = $this->entity::whereNot('id', $entity->id)
                    // also except the ones we already found
                    ->whereNotIn('id', $related->modelKeys())
                    // and only get those which also have current relationship (e.g. tags)
                    ->whereHas($relation, function (Builder $query) use($relationIds, $relation) {
                        $query->whereIn($relation . '.id', $relationIds);
                    })
                    ->get()
                    ->sortKeysDesc()
                    ->take(10);

                $related = $related->concat($relationEntities->except($related->modelKeys()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works well. So I could load a blog post, for instance, and show related blog posts that have some of the same tags by calling:

```
$post = Post::find(1);
$related = $this->getRelated($post, [], ['tags']);
```

Now, I also need to respect other types than tags, hence `$relations` is an array: "Show me related blog posts that have any of these tags, categories, you name it, in common."

My first problem was in the subquery. [I had to hardcode the id in the relation table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563994/laravel-relationship-column-id-in-where-clause-is-ambiguous):

`$query->whereIn('id', $relationIds);`
had to be
`$query->whereIn($relation . '.id', $relationIds);`

So now my problem is that `$relation . '.id'` doesnt work for all cases. The relationship `fooBars()` would expect `foo_bar.id` but looks for `fooBar.id`.

Is there no automatic way of Laravel automatically knowing the column name based on the relationship I am currently querying? If not, I must, for each relatioship I am querying, define the column name (of the id) of the relationship table. Is there something I am missing?

Or can I somehow load the relationship and look at the DB scheme? Whats best practice here?

One way could be to use snake case (`$query->whereIn(Str::of($relation)->snake() . '.id', $relationIds);`) but that feels vague and dirty.

All of these are polymorphic morphToMany/ morphedByMany.

---

Edit: For better understanding I'm adding an example of what my models look like. They all use default naming conventions. Again, I want to get related Posts that have either some Tags or FooBars in common.

```
<?php

class Post extends Entity
{
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Tag::class, 'taggable');
    }

    public function fooBars()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(FooBar::class, 'foo_barable');
    }    
}

class Tag extends Entity
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Post::class, 'taggable');
    }
}

class FooBar extends Entity
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Post::class, 'foo_barable');
    }
}
```

Comment: I have done something similar in the past, can you share few examples of **$relations** array not just tags, also are you using proper naming convention when handling relationships in the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I made a mini version of your code to show concept:** You can build on it to load inner relationships or do changes to relationships that are loaded.

```
$post = Post::first();
$related = $this->getRelated($post, ['tags', 'tags', 'tags', 'brands', 'somethingStrange']);
```

**The getRelated function:**

```
public function getRelated($entity, $relations = []) {
    if (count($relations)) {
        array_unique($relations);
    
        $verifiedRelationships = [];
        $verifiedRelationshipsPrimaryKey = [];
    
        foreach ($relations as $relation) {
            //If this method exists in the parent class continue
            if(method_exists($entity, $relation)) {
                //add the relation
                array_push($verifiedRelationships, $relation);
                //add the relation primary_id
                array_push($verifiedRelationshipsPrimaryKey, Str::lower(Str::singular(Str::snake(Str::studly($relation)))).'_id');
            }
        }
        
        $entity->load($verifiedRelationships);
    }
}
```

This will automatically load all related methods that are found in that class.

**Few notes:**

1. `$verifiedRelationships` will return any found methods `['tags', 'brands', 'somethingStrange']`
2. `$verifiedRelationshipsPrimaryKey` will return `['tag_id', 'brand_id', 'something_strange_id']`
3. Laravel has a function on the model that gets the key using `getKeyName();`
4. Laravel has a function on the model to return the qualified relationship id using `getQualifiedKeyName()`

**Example of $model Primary Key inside the foreach loop:**

```
$relatedClass = get_class($entity->$relation()->getRelated());
                    
$primaryKey = ($instance = new $relatedClass)->getKeyName();

//returns "id"
```

**Example of the $relationship Primary key inside the foreach loop:**

```
$relatedClass = get_class($entity->$relation()->getRelated());
                    
$primaryKey = ($instance = new $relatedClass)->getQualifiedKeyName();

//returns "post_brands.id"
```

Please test this out, and if you want changes or have other cases for relationships or clarifications, I would be happy to adjust the code until it works for you, I honestly don't know the relationships you have, it would be easier if I can get an array example.

Comment: Hey there, thank you very much for sharing your code. This is quite similar to what I've tried but I didnt know about the `getKeyName()` etc. functions. I will try it out.

Comment: I've added some very basic model examples. Entity is just extending the default Model which is irrelevant in this case.

Comment: Hey @KGG, you helped me a lot here. I wondered whether you also have an idea for my latest question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75247718/how-to-programmatically-get-relationship-data-without-having-a-model-instance Thanks for having a look!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @KGG's answer I came up with the following:

```
 <?php
    
    if (count($relations)) {
        foreach ($relations as $relation) {
            if ($entity->{$relation}()->exists()) {
                $relationIds = $entity->{$relation}()->get()->modelKeys();
                $relatedClass = get_class($entity->$relation()->getRelated());
                $relationPrimaryKey = ($instance = new $relatedClass)->getQualifiedKeyName();
    
                $relationEntities = $this->entity::whereNot('id', $entity->id)
                    ->whereNotIn('id', $related->modelKeys())
                    ->whereHas($relation, function (Builder $query) use($relationIds, $relationPrimaryKey) {
                        $query->whereIn($relationPrimaryKey, $relationIds);
                    })
                    ->get()
                    ->sortKeysDesc()
                    ->take(10)
                    ;
    
                $related = $related->concat($relationEntities->except($related->modelKeys()));
            }
        }
    }
```